# Uploading large files with PHP

Tags: .htaccess, file-upload, php

I am dealing with PHP File Upload. First I am trying with Just HTML/PHP code without any uploaders (uploadify) etc.

The HTML Code

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="upload">Select : </label>
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="upload" multiple="multiple" />
    <!-- 1024 x 1024 x 1024 -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1073741824" />
    <input type="submit" name="fsubmit" id="fsubmit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

The PHP Code

```
if (isset($_FILES['file_upload']) && $_FILES['file_upload']['error'] == 0) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name'], '../somepath/.../' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name');
} else {
    echo $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
}
```

It is uploading the files less then 8Mb. To override the PHP default I change `.htaccess` to this and restarted apache.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M # also tried "1024M"
php_value post_max_size 1024M # also tried "1024M"
php_value max_execution_time 3600
php_value max_input_time 3600
```

But no luck, it always takes default `8M`. I also try to change the settings from PHP code on the fly like this

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1024M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');
ini_set('max_input_time', '600');
ini_set('memory_limit', -1); // no memory limit
```

This has also no effect, when I `echo ini_get('post_max_size')` it shows `8M`. The error code return is 2. Show PHP says

```
UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE

Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
```

Now my question is Why it is not able to override from `.htacess` or PHP code? **NOTE** I am on VPS server. When I change 8M to `xM` manually it works. Hope I am clear, thanks in advance...

Comment: what is the value of these variables you are getting using ini_get(),I suppose its not getting overridden

Comment: @zamil, I already said that it is not overridden, but why?

Comment: please contact your hosting company and ask them whether they applied any cap on maximum value of these variables.an eg:http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/php-settings-that-cannot-be-changed

Comment: You didn't read the question? I write a note that I am on VPS there is no cap. Also I write I can do this manually but can't from php code or apache htaccess.

Comment: sorry, i din't c that.for VPS there is no cap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missed to add "AllowOverride All" in apache config for the site directory...because of this your values in htaccess are not overridden..

check these links

http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1809

http://blog.triphp.com/lessons/htaccess/allow-override

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you edit directly php.ini with something like this:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 750M
php_value post_max_size 750M
```

and it works, what's the problem? You are not being able to do it in the other way, but what's wrong this way?

Comment: editing directly `php.ini` is not a good solution. you cannot do this in shared servers.

Comment: sounds logic. Sorry I can't help you then.